# How to loop via columns in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to output text file from some sample excel files.

So that I created following samples.

after opening text file , each rows are printed.

But when I try to loop over columns , these values are appended in one columns

Are there any good way to achieve row and column based loop ?

This text file uses comma separator.

Thanks.

```
 Sub Test_Open()
      Dim strFilePath As String
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      
      
      strFilePath = "C:\Users\test\text.txt" 
     
      Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\test.xlsx"
        
      Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("test")
      
      Open strFilePath For Output As #1
      
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim column As Integer
        
        row = 7
        Do Until ws.Cells(row, 2).Value = ""
           For column = 1 To 86
                Print #1, ws.Cells(row, column)
           Next
           row = row + 1
        Loop

      Close #1
     
    End Sub
```

Comment: What separator does the text file uses? Is it comma, Tab, something else?

Comment: this text file uses comma separator, thanks !

Comment: Ok. Are there the same number of columns on each text file row? Does it have headers in its first line? If yes (or not), can be the first row/line considered like having the necessary number of columns? In fact, if not something confidential, can you share the used text file?

Comment: yes , there are same number of columns on each files row .

Comment: Then, please try the code I posted. It builds an array, working fast, only in memory and drops the result at once, at the end. Can you share such a file, even a dummy one? I would like to test the code...

Answer (score 1):

You can add some variable to hold all your column information.

Change your code

```vb
For column = 1 To 86
    Print #1, ws.Cells(row, column)
Next
```

To this code.

```vb
Dim cols As String
' Add all column separated by comma(,)
For column = 1 To 86
    cols = cols & "," & ws.Cells(row, column)
Next
' Trim first comma(,)
cols = Mid(cols, 2)
' Write column to one line at last
Print #1, cols
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save it with [Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) as *.csv with requered options

```
Sub Test_Open()
    Dim strFilePath As String
    strFilePath = "c:\test\text.txt"
    
    With Workbooks.Open("c:\test\test.xlsx").Worksheets("test")
        .SaveAs strFilePath, xlCSV
        .Parent.Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Test_Open()
      Dim strFilePath As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
      Dim i As Long, j As Long, txtArr, colArr, nrCol As Long, arrFin
      
      strFilePath = "C:\Users\test\text.txt"
     
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test.xlsx")
      Set ws = wb.Worksheets("test")
      txtArr = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strFilePath, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
      nrCol = UBound(Split(txtArr(0), ","))
      ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(txtArr) - 6, 1 To nrCol)
      For i = 6 To UBound(txtArr)
            colArr = Split(txtArr(i), ",")
            For j = 0 To nrCol
                arrFin(i + 1, j + 1) = colArr(j)
            Next j
      Next
      ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

The code is not tested. If you would share the file you use, I will test it and eventually optimize something, if the case...

If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. I can comment the lines which look more difficult to be understood.

Comment: @Heisenberg Didn't you find some time to test the received solutions? It is at least polite to send some feedback when somebody spends some time (only) in order to help you. I am not speaking only about my answer. It is good to test them and let us know what's wrong with the tested pieces of code...